# addEventListenerで、クリックした要素そのものを受け取りたい

Tags: javascript

**質問**
addEventListenerで、クリックした要素そのもの(id未指定)を受け取るには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？
・渡す側で何とかしてループ処理するしかない？

**現状**
・onclick

```
<div id="area">
  <button onclick="hoge(this);">1</button>
  <button onclick="hoge(this);">2</button>
</div>

<script>
  function hoge(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
</script>
```

**やりたいこと**
・addEventListenerで、クリックした要素(divではなくbutton)を受け取りたい

```
<div id="area">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
</div>

<script>
  function hoge() {
    console.log(this); 
    //ここでクリックした要素(divではなくbutton)を受け取りたい
  }
  var el = document.getElementById("area");
  el.addEventListener("click",hoge, false);
</script>
```

**その他**
・buttonタグには、id名class名を付与しない
・buttonタグは動的生成のため、階層構造は変化する(生成の度に前後にノードを挿入する可能性あり)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

イベントハンドラで Event を受け取るようにすれば、[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Event/target) でイベントを発生させた要素を参照できます

```
function hoge(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
}
```